# Why do I have the Custodian badge?

Tags: discussion

I don't recall carrying out any review tasks on The Workplace. Why is this occurring?

Comment: so far you did one review is Suggested Edits. Review history is public by design, [here is yours](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/48356/peter-david-carter?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Comment: I looked. It certainly said I have... but I have never had enough rep to access the review queue, so how would that be possible?

Comment: It was edit suggested to your post. "Any user can review suggested edit on his _own_ posts without having enough privilege. " ([How can a user with less than 10 rep can do a review on suggested edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207061/165773))

Comment: Hhhhhhhhmmmmmmm. So other users can allocate review tasks to me, as long as it's my own? Because there's a separate badge for just 'editing' a post...

Comment: in a sense yes. Since you have a right to review suggested edits to your posts one can say that reviewing these is "allocated" to you (along with other reviewers who have sufficient rep to review any edit)

Answer (score 7):

When somebody proposes an edit to your post, you receive a notification.  If you click through and approve that edit, that counts as reviewing a suggested edit.  So even if you don't have enough reputation to access the review queue, you can end up doing a review under specialized circumstances.  The first time you do that, you get the badge.

I believe that Suggested Edits is the only review queue where this sort of thing can currently happen.

Comment: Ah! I don't seem to see those very often so I just assumed they only occurred under special circumstances.